# contacts data in xcode

Tags: xcode, contacts, abaddressbook, abrecordref

Everybody..
I am trying to develop an app for iPhone which basicly deals with `ABAddressBook` and contacts data...
My goal is  to send all the contacts data (at first step, names and phones) in a file by e-mail..

Now, I am trying to reach the contacts data, and I want to add them to two different arrays, names and phones arrays..

At first, I am trying to see all the datas in the screen when i pressed a button "List Contacts". the datas should be seen on the screen. and then when i pressed the second button "Send Contacts", it should send the file to an e-mail account.. This is how my apps will work..

I am having problems at showing the data on the screen.. I wrote something but it doesn't give anything on the screen in a textView.. 
Can you help me to solve this problem?

Here's the code for listing the contacts (listCon method):

---

```
-(IBAction)listCon:(id)sender
{

    NSMutableArray *names = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    NSMutableArray *numbers1= [[NSMutableArray array] init];

    NSMutableArray *numbers2= [[NSMutableArray array] init];

    NSMutableArray *numbers3= [[NSMutableArray array] init];

    ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreate();

    if (addressBook != nil)
    {

        NSLog(@"Successfully accessed the address book.");

        CFArrayRef allPeople = ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(addressBook);
        CFIndex nPeople= ABAddressBookGetPersonCount(addressBook);

        NSUInteger peopleCounter = 0;
        for (peopleCounter = 0;peopleCounter < nPeople; peopleCounter++)
        {

            ABRecordRef thisPerson = CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(allPeople,peopleCounter);

            NSString *contactFirstLast = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%,%",ABRecordCopyValue(thisPerson, kABPersonFirstNameProperty), ABRecordCopyValue(thisPerson,kABPersonLastNameProperty)];

            [names insertObject:contactFirstLast atIndex:peopleCounter];

            ABMultiValueRef phoneNumbers = ABRecordCopyValue(thisPerson,kABPersonPhoneProperty);

            NSString *firstPhone = (__bridge_transfer NSString*) ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(phoneNumbers, 0);

            NSString *secondPhone = (__bridge_transfer NSString*) ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(phoneNumbers, 1);

            NSString *thirdPhone = (__bridge_transfer NSString*) ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(phoneNumbers, 2);

            [numbers1 insertObject:firstPhone atIndex:peopleCounter];
            [numbers2 insertObject:secondPhone atIndex:peopleCounter];                             
            [numbers3 insertObject:thirdPhone atIndex:peopleCounter];
    }          
}

myView.text=[names componentsJoinedByString:@"\n\n"];     

myView.text=[numbers1 componentsJoinedByString:@"\n\n"];    

myView.text=[numbers2 componentsJoinedByString:@"\n\n"];

myView.text=[numbers3 componentsJoinedByString:@"\n\n"];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just glancing at your code, you can't do this:

```
NSString *contactFirstLast = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%,%",ABRecordCopyValue(thisPerson, kABPersonFirstNameProperty), ABRecordCopyValue(thisPerson,kABPersonLastNameProperty)];
```

There are several errors: first off `%` in your `stringWithFormat:` is not a format specifier; you probably are thinking of `%@`. Second off, copying the value of `kABPersonFirstNameProperty` will return a `CFStringRef`, and that's not what you want to display the name in a text field. You'll have to toll-free bridge the result of `ABRecordCopyValue()`. You can do this by adding this line - `(__bridge_transfer NSString *)` - in front of your `ABRecordCopyValue()`'s. With all the corrections, it should look like this:

```
NSString *contactFirstLast = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@,%@", (__bridge_transfer NSString *)ABRecordCopyValue(thisPerson, kABPersonFirstNameProperty), (__bridge_transfer NSString *)ABRecordCopyValue(thisPerson,kABPersonLastNameProperty)];
```

Hope this help (might not cover all errors)!